# IOS DeviceActivityCenter - Multiple Schedules and Activities at Once

Tags: ios

I am developing an app using IOS DeviceActivityCenter. I am blocking apps using IntervalDidStart and the startMonitoring function, however I have run into a problem. When I try to run multiple DeviceActivityNames and DeviceActivitySchedules at once, the startMonitoring functions overwrite each other. I want to make it so that I can run multiple instances at once, and the schedules can overlap without interfering with the shields of the other schedule.

I tried everything and nothing worked

Comment: What do you mean by "the startMonitoring functions overwrite each other"?  Are you getting an error thrown or do you not receive call backs for one of your activities?  [edit] your question to show relevant code